# Is there a security issue with fit4less requiring bank information and not simply card number?

Tags: credit-card, banks, information-gathering

When I set up timed payments I tend to prefer setting them up through my credit card. As this tends to be more reliable in case of over charges, etc.

For example spotify goes through my credit card. The setup was done by entering my credit card number and the cvc on the back.

If you try and sign up for fit4less on their website, it requires that you enter all of your banking information, transit number, institution number, etc.

Is there any kind of security issue with providing all this information to a company? It feels sketchy giving all this information that they seemingly don't need.

Comment: Which country are you in?

Comment: Providing the banking information instead of a credit card number is actually not uncommon, at least in Germany. As for the associated risk of fraudulent charges - these depend on your local laws and in part maybe also on your contract with your bank. Thus this is more a legal question which would be more on-topic on [law.se] but where you of course need to provide the necessary information so that others can decide which laws and regulations apply in your case.

Comment: @akozi In many countries, if you want to set up recurring payments, this is the accepted way to do it. Note that the information they request is no different from what is on a cheque.

Comment: My country im living in is Canada.

Comment: Thanks for the quick comments everyone. Im just getting to work now and will be active around lunch. Cheers.

Comment: Pre-authorized debits are very common for Gyms in Canada, but I've usually had to provide a paper form in person. I'd be a little nervous about submitting the details online too, but it does't make it any less legitimate as far as I am aware.

Comment: By the way... what you're setting up is not a Credit Card payment at all. It's a pre-authorized debit. There are implications for your liability and they are a lot harder to cancel. You might want to look into that... but you'd be hard-pressed to find a Gym that doesn't use Pe-Authorized debits in Canada. The difficulty in cancelling them is part of their business model... as shady as that is.